# The hash that jBCrypt generates isn't the same as that of server

Tags: java, mysql

My current code is this:

```
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
                    String username = usernameBox.getText(), password = passwordBox.getText();
                    String pwHash = BCrypt.hashpw(password, BCrypt.gensalt(12));

                    PreparedStatement login = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM core_members WHERE name=? AND members_pass_hash=?");
                    login.setString(1, username);
                    login.setString(2, pwHash);
                    ResultSet rs = login.executeQuery();
                    if(rs.next()){
                        // correct username and pass
                    } else {
                        // wrong username and pass
                    }
```

When I tried replacing `pwHash` with the hash on the database it works, I am using `Invision Community 4.4.10` for more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using a *random* salt to generate a hash. Then you try to find a hash that matches it. Of course, you will find nothing.

Instead, you should use *the same* hash as you used for this username. Your steps should be briefly as follows:

1. Look up for an entry using `username` only.
2. If not found, exit.
3. Extract the salt from the found entry.
4. Calculate hash using given password and extracted salt.
5. Compare if the calculated hash equals to the hash in the found entry.